# Post a message to the user based on bool answer - FormFlow/Bot Framework

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, formflow

I can't seem to find a way to post a message to the user in the FormFlow based on how the user answers a bool. To post Fields based a previous answer you can use:

```
 .Field(new FieldReflector<GetQuoteDialog>(nameof(Dothis))
            .SetActive((state) => state.isDone== true))
```

However I haven't found a way to do the same with the .Message(). So say if I want to just send the message "Congrats!", then post the next question in the formflow.

So the dialog I would like to play out would be like:

1. true/false question
2. user answers true
3. post message "Congrats" if user answers true
4. ask next true/false question

Is there a way that I am just missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the second parameter of `.Message()` which is condition delegate function, from source code:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Show a message that does not require a response.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   message:
    //     A \ref patterns string to fill in and send.
    //
    //   condition:
    //     Whether or not this step is active.
    //
    //   dependencies:
    //     Fields message depends on.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     Modified IFormBuilder.
    IFormBuilder<T> Message(string message, ActiveDelegate<T> condition = null, IEnumerable<string> dependencies = null);
```

So, please try:

```
.Message("Congrats", condition: (form) => form.boolField == true)
```

Comment: Works! I did think it was to do with that but I couldnt find an example online of where it was used. Thanks very much for your help